# Error 1236 - "Could not find first log file name in binary log index file"

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

Our setup:

- Master: MariaDB 10.0.21
- Slave: MariaDB 10.0.17

Replication was working fine until recently at which point the slave's DBs had to be restored from a dump.  I performed all of the necessary steps: Dump the master's DBs, transfer the dump to the slave, drop the old DBs, execute the dump to restore the DBs, execute the appropriate `CHANGE MASTER` command, and finally `START SLAVE`.

I am receiving the error:
`Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'`

The first log file that the slave needs from the master is `mysql-bin.000289`.  I can see that this is present on the master:
[image]

I can also see that the binary log index on the master seems to have an entry for this log file:
[image]

Still replication is not working - I keep getting the same error.  I'm out of ideas - what should I check next?

---

Updated: Output of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` as requested:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
--------------
SHOW SLAVE STATUS
--------------

*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: 
                  Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Master_User: replication
                  Master_Port: 1234
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000289
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 342
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000289
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: xxx_yyy,xxx_zzz
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 342
              Relay_Log_Space: 248
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1236
                Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 3
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
                   Using_Gtid: No
                  Gtid_IO_Pos: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Additional requested information:

```
root@master [818 18:54:22 /var/lib/mysql]# ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000289
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1074010194 May 19 03:28 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000289
root@master [819 18:54:29 /var/lib/mysql]# ls mysql-bin.00029*
mysql-bin.000290  mysql-bin.000291  mysql-bin.000292 #(Yes, it was created)
root@master [821 18:56:52 /var/lib/mysql]# mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 6345382
Server version: 10.0.21-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
+------------------+------------+
| Log_name         | File_size  |
+------------------+------------+
| mysql-bin.000279 | 1074114047 |
| mysql-bin.000280 | 1074004090 |
| mysql-bin.000281 | 1074035416 |
| mysql-bin.000282 | 1073895128 |
| mysql-bin.000283 | 1073742000 |
| mysql-bin.000284 | 1074219591 |
| mysql-bin.000285 | 1074184547 |
| mysql-bin.000286 | 1074217812 |
| mysql-bin.000287 | 1022733058 |
| mysql-bin.000288 |     265069 |
| mysql-bin.000289 | 1074010194 |
| mysql-bin.000290 | 1074200346 |
| mysql-bin.000291 |  617421886 |
| mysql-bin.000292 |     265028 |
+------------------+------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> exit
Bye
root@master [821 18:57:24 /var/lib/mysql]# mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000289 > /tmp/somefile.txt
root@master [822 18:58:13 /var/lib/mysql]# tail /tmp/somefile.txt 
# at 1074010124
#160519  3:28:59 server id 5  end_log_pos 1074010151    Xid = 417608063
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 1074010151
#160519  3:28:59 server id 5  end_log_pos 1074010194    Rotate to mysql-bin.000290  pos: 4
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */;
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=0*/;
root@master [823 18:58:31 /var/lib/mysql]#
```

`/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf` (excerpt):

```
# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1
```

---

Edit: Postion 342 does seem to exist:

```
root@master [826 12:15:33 /var/lib/mysql]# grep "end_log_pos 342 " /tmp/somefile.txt
#160517 14:43:13 server id 5  end_log_pos 342   Binlog checkpoint mysql-bin.000288
```

Comment: Also beware as your master version is slightly more recent than your slave version. While slave version can be higher (because it will undoubtedly understand all command/functions/features), if the Master is more recent, it could invoke something the Slave has never heard of. I suspect it would not occur in such a minor revision difference, but can't be ruled out and would undoubtedly be Arcane in the extreme and difficult to find. Also: the official line is that more recent master is not supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to not be connecting to the master that you think you are.  Per your binary logs on the master you seem to have:

#160519  3:28:59 **server id 5**

But per SHOW SLAVE STATUS we see:

```
         Master_Server_Id: 3
```

And further you seem to be connecting on localhost, but you implied your master/slave are on different hosts:

```
              Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: We're using SSH tunneling (with [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/)) to expose the remote master locally at `127.0.0.1:3305`.  I noticed the Master_Server_Id as well, but I figured that was just a remnant from long ago when we were using a different master.  I was expecting the value in `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` to update once we had fully reestablished replication.  Regardless, this is an awesome suggestion; I'll triple-check that we are, indeed, connecting to the right master!

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!  We were, indeed, connecting to the wrong master.  I confirmed it by doing a `telnet 127.0.0.1:3305` - I could see that the reported MySQL version matched the version from the *old* master.  I think the root of the problem was likely due to some DNS quirks on our network - it seems that the autossh connection was erroneously established to domain.com, even though it was configured to connect to db.domain.com.  Thanks so much yet again.

Answer (score 12):

If all else fails, you may find that you need to reset the slave and restart replication. From https://www.redips.net/mysql/replication-slave-relay-log-corrupted/ :

```
# First note current settings (note Relay_Master_Log_File and Exec_Master_Log_Pos)
mysql> show slave status\G
# then stop slave
mysql> stop slave;
# make slave forget its replication position in the master's binary log
mysql> reset slave;
# change slave to start reading from stopped position
mysql> change master to master_log_file='mysql-bin.XXX', master_log_pos=XXX;
# start slave
mysql> start slave;
```

Comment: The OP has commented that another answer was correct (and they were connecting to the wrong instance).

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ - yes, but half the point of Stackexchange is for the archive of the questions, which inevitably land at the top of Google searches for other people with the same problem. I had the exact same problem myself, and this was the solution for me (especially as I literally spent hours trying to solve it, because most other pages only show the same other answers). The fact that the other "wrong" answer has 2 up-votes is testament to this.

Comment: Yes, fair point. As long as this (suggestion) is meant to be used when all else fail (and clearly marked as such), that's fine. That's why I only commented and not downvoted.

Comment: This answer worked for me when none of the other advice applied.  (I was working off an existing, current binlog, had the master properly configured, etc.)  It's a sound answer and frankly the RESET SLAVE; option should be mentioned more prominently above.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is the answer.

Look at the output of `SHOW BINARY LOGS` query:

```
+------------------+------------+
| Log_name         | File_size  |
+------------------+------------+
| mysql-bin.000279 | 1074114047 |
| mysql-bin.000280 | 1074004090 |
| mysql-bin.000281 | 1074035416 |
| mysql-bin.000282 | 1073895128 |
```

There is no mysql-bin.000278 in the display.

Unless the binary logs rotated, the contents of mysql-bin.index is wrong.

Please compare the contents of `mysql-bin.index` with the binlogs files now existing and make sure they match. You can fix this on the Master with

```
mysql> PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.000279';
```

then go to the Slave and run

```
mysql> STOP SLAVE; START SLAVE;
```

**Give it a Try !!!**

Comment: Hi, Rolando!  Thanks so much for your help!  Unfortunately, I'm still confused.  Did you mean `mysql-bin.000288` instead of `mysql-bin.000278`?  If so, `mysql-bin.000288` does seem to exist.  Will this still fix the problem?

Comment: `PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.000279';` gave me an error (as was to be expected), since log "279" no longer existed (had been rotated out). `PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.000288';` executed successfully, and deleted all binary logs up to "288".  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed suggestions, Rolando!  The problem ended up being that we were connecting to the wrong master (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/140259/55530).

Answer (score 5):

*Update: This answer covers the general error classification. For a more specific answer about how to best handle the OP's exact query, please see other answers to this question*

One of the top most critical replication error **Got fatal error 1236**
It can be triggered by multiple reasons, one of them is the title of this question.

> Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log:
>   ‘Could not find first log file name in binary log index file’

**This error occurs when the slave server required binary log for replication no longer exists on the master database server.**

So many scenarios can cause this:

- The master server expired binary logs via system variable
  `expire_logs_days` (my.cnf if you set `expire_logs_days` old binlogs
  expire automatically and are removed; When MySQL opens a new binlog
  file, it checks the older binlogs, and purges any that are older than
  the value of expire_logs_days)
- Someone manually deleted binary logs from master via `PURGE BINARY LOGS` command or via `rm -f` command
- You have some `cronjob` which archives older binary logs to claim disk
  space

In order to resolve this problem, the only **clean** solution I can think of is to re-create the slave server from a master server backup or from other slave in replication topology.

Reference : [mysql replication got fatal error](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/10/08/mysql-replication-got-fatal-error-1236-causes-and-cures/)