# Contradictory reports from MySQL that a binlog file exists

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, binlog, mysqlbinlog

Our replication recently stopped working.  I submitted a question but was unsuccessful in fixing the problem ([Error 1236 - "Could not find first log file name in binary log index file"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/139131/55530)).  Since the occurrence of the events described in the question, I've executed a `RESET MASTER` on the master, a `RESET SLAVE` on the slave, and created a new full dump, but am still getting the same results.

I thought I'd take a step back and try taking a different approach, attacking the specifics of the error message itself.

When I execute `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on the slave, it reports that the master cannot "find first log file name":

```
Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'
```

The "first log file name" is `/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000001`:

```
root@master [905 13:30:56 /var/lib/mysql]# cat mysql-bin.index
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000001
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000002
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000003
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000004
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000005
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000006
```

MySQL itself seems to be aware that `mysql-bin.000001` is the first binary log:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
+------------------+------------+
| Log_name         | File_size  |
+------------------+------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |      10421 |
| mysql-bin.000002 | 1073919628 |
| mysql-bin.000003 | 1074488806 |
| mysql-bin.000004 | 1073744707 |
| mysql-bin.000005 | 1074366770 |
| mysql-bin.000006 | 1069984818 |
+------------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`mysqlbinlog` shows that this file seems to be accessible and valid:

```
root@master [911 13:48:04 /var/lib/mysql]# mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000001
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=1*/;
/*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
# at 4
#160526 12:24:14 server id 5  end_log_pos 248   Start: binlog v 4, server v 10.0.21-MariaDB-log created 160526 12:24:14 at startup
```

MySQL itself also seems to have access to this first log file:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW BINLOG EVENTS in 'mysql-bin.000001' from 0 limit 4;
+------------------+-----+-------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Log_name         | Pos | Event_type        | Server_id | End_log_pos | Info                                           |
+------------------+-----+-------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |   4 | Format_desc       |         5 |         248 | Server ver: 10.0.21-MariaDB-log, Binlog ver: 4 |
| mysql-bin.000001 | 248 | Gtid_list         |         5 |         273 | []                                             |
| mysql-bin.000001 | 273 | Binlog_checkpoint |         5 |         312 | mysql-bin.000001                               |
| mysql-bin.000001 | 312 | Gtid              |         5 |         350 | BEGIN GTID 0-5-1                               |
+------------------+-----+-------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## Question

To recap, MySQL is complaining that it "Could not find first log file name in binary log index file".  However, as shown above, it appears that MySQL does know what the "first log file name" is, and it can, indeed, access it.

**What else should I check to ensure that MySQL can actually "find [the] first log file name"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was that we were connecting to an old (wrong) master.  The previous master was `domain.com`, but many months ago, we migrated to `db.domain.com`.  It seems that we were erroneously connecting to `domain.com`.

We’re using `autossh` to set up SSH tunnels for our replication.  To confirm that we were connecting to the old (wrong) master, I executed `telnet 127.0.0.1:3305` on the slave.  From this, I could see that the reported MySQL version matched the version from the old master.  I did a full reboot of the slave which seems to have fixed the problem.  I think the root of the problem was likely due to some DNS quirks on our network - it would seem that when the autossh connection was established, `db.domain.com` resolved to `domain.com`, hence the symptoms of connecting to the wrong master.  (Certainly, these DNS issues on our network are something to look into)

Note: Major thanks to @Andrew for his answer on the original question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/140259/55530