# Getting fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log in mariadb master master replication

Tags: mysql, mariadb, master-master-replication

I am facing the situation similar to this [Error 1236 - "Could not find first log file name in binary log index file"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139131/error-1236-could-not-find-first-log-file-name-in-binary-log-index-file?newreg=4677761266604ec98e94e511bac681c0)

I have tried all the answers but I am still not able to get rid of this error on Server id = 1:

```
         Last_IO_Errno: 1236
         Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'
```

I have two nodes running mariadb 10 the master node Server id 1 and and second master node Server id = 2

Server id 1:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: 
                   Master_Host: 192.168.1.10
                   Master_User: replicator
                   Master_Port: 6306
                 Connect_Retry: 60
               Master_Log_File: mariadb-bin.000001
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 313
                Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000001
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 4
         Relay_Master_Log_File: mariadb-bin.000001
              Slave_IO_Running: No
             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
               Replicate_Do_DB: 
           Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
            Replicate_Do_Table: 
        Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                    Last_Errno: 0
                    Last_Error: 
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 313
               Relay_Log_Space: 256
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File: 
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File: 
            Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
               Master_SSL_Cert: 
             Master_SSL_Cipher: 
                Master_SSL_Key: 
         Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 1236
                 Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'
                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                Last_SQL_Error: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
              Master_Server_Id: 2
                Master_SSL_Crl: 
            Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
                    Using_Gtid: No
                   Gtid_IO_Pos: 
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                 Parallel_Mode: conservative
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 0
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

checked binary logs:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
+------------------+-----------+
| Log_name         | File_size |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |  11337613 |
| mysql-bin.000002 |    138563 |
| mysql-bin.000003 |   1100347 |
| mysql-bin.000004 |   7406418 |
| mysql-bin.000005 | 110683302 |
| mysql-bin.000006 |    144929 |
+------------------+-----------+
MariaDB [(none)]> show master status;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000006 |   173699 |              |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

then Server id 2:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.1.11
                  Master_User: replicator
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000006
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 125740
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 10034
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000006
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 125740
              Relay_Log_Space: 10337
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
                   Using_Gtid: No
                  Gtid_IO_Pos: 
      Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                Parallel_Mode: conservative
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and binary logs:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
+------------------+-----------+
| Log_name         | File_size |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |       313 |
+------------------+-----------+

MariaDB [(none)]> show master status;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |      313 |              |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

I do have backup of database , but I still want to understand and fix the issue rather then restarting from beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `sync_binlog = OFF`, this may fix the problem:

`STOP SLAVE; START SLAVE;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but I notice that on server id 1 the slave status says it's looking for a master log file called `mariadb-bin.{digits}` whereas the bin logs on its master (server id 2) are named `mysql-bin.{digits}`. I think you need to make these names match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `CHANGE MASTER TO` and change the `Master_Log_File` to the filename used on the master of the other server.

While different filenames isn't a problem its rather confusing.